# Dropbox making duplicate files

Tags: dropbox

My Dropbox keeps making duplicate copies of files, e.g. Becker Job and saving it as Becker Job(1). What is causing this and how do I stop it?

Comment: I just had this issue after powering up a Galaxy Tab 3 after a couple weeks.  Didn't take it with me so it sat powered off.  When I turned it on, I started seeing files being added to dropbox rather quickly.  (1) and (1)(1) in the file names.  Seemed it was in a loop.  I just shut off wifi, signed out.  Signing back in seemed to solve it.

Answer (score 5):

It's not Dropbox making those duplicates. (When Dropbox has an edit conflict it puts "(Username's conflicted copy yyyy-mm-dd)" after the filename.)

Most likely what is happening is that you, or you and someone you share a folder with, are copying files with the same names to the Dropbox folder and your operating system (I'm guessing Windows) is renaming the second file to avoid overwriting the file.

Check your [Dropbox Events](https://www.dropbox.com/events) log to see when these files are being added, and by whom.

Answer (score 2):

Is the file a Microsoft Office file? Or a file from a program that has auto save or auto backup features?

I was having the same problem and discovered that it was Microsoft Office's auto save feature creating the duplicates. On your normal file system, it just overwrites the file on disk, however, Dropbox must be saving the auto save file as a duplicate.